# Can I convert a JSON string into JsonResult?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, jsonresult

I have some stored JSON strings stored in the DB which I want to return to the client as JsonResult . I know that Json(object) turns an object into JsonResult but what if I already have the result in a string ? can I cast it to JsonResult

Answer (score 140):

You don't need to return a `JsonResult` because its job is to serialize an *object* into JSON string.  You already have the JSON string, so just return it in a ContentResult and specify the correct content type:

```
string json = //get some json from your DB
return new ContentResult { Content = json, ContentType = "application/json" };
```

Remember that your MVC action methods should all have `ActionResult` as a return type, so you can return `ContentResult` just as easily as `JsonResult`.

Comment: There is also a `Content` method similar to the `Json` method, so you can write `return Content(json, "application/json");`.