# C# Return Controller data to JSONP output for autocomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, jsonp

I'm struggling a little bit with outputting controller data in C# MVC, to JSONP, for use with JQuery autocomplete. All i want to do, is take 2 parameters, and a callback for JSONP to work, and the query return the matching course titles available, based on the search.

**CourseController.cs**

```
    public JsonResult GetPredictiveCourseTitleSearchResults()
    {
        var jsonbuilder = "";
        var q = HttpContext.Request.Params["q"];
        var year = HttpContext.Request.Params["year"];
        var callback = HttpContext.Request.Params["callback"];
        var model = new courseModel
        {
            SearchList = GetCourses(q,year)
        };
        var results = model.SearchList.Items.ToList();
        int count = results.Count();
        int resultCount = 0;

        if (callback != "")
        {
            jsonbuilder += callback + "(";
        }
        jsonbuilder += "[";
        foreach(var result in results)
        {

            if(resultCount+1 == count)
            {
                jsonbuilder += "{\"title\":" + "\"" + result.Fields["title"].ToString() + "\"}";
            }
            else
            {
                jsonbuilder += "{\"title\":" + "\"" + result.Fields["title"].ToString() + "\"},";
            }

            resultCount++;
        }
        jsonbuilder += "]";
        if (callback != "")
        {
            jsonbuilder += ")";
        }
        return Json(jsonbuilder, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**CourseModel.cs**

```
public class courseModel
{
    public ListModel<Item> SearchList { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

}
```

**App.js**

```
 $("#course_search_input")
     .bind("keydown", function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
             $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
             event.preventDefault();
         }
     })
    .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://leedsbeckett/search/getpredictivecoursetitlesearchresults/",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    q: request.q,
                    year: $("#selectedyear").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response( $.map( data.stuff, function ( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.title,
                            value: item.title
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (XHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {

                    alert("Data"+data);
                    alert("XHR error: " + XHR);
                    alert("error: " + textStatus);
                    alert("error: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
              "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
              "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
```

**Output of JSON file**

```
"jQuery1111023084966000169516_1457628798511([{\"title\":\"Course title example\"}])"
```

This however isn't loaded, it just errors in the JQuery, with data unknown.

I've also tried:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        CourseJSON [] courses = js.Deserialize<CourseJSON[]>(jsonbuilder);
return Json(courses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But this gave an error due to it not recognising the callback prefix.

Any help would be much appreciated, as i'm not sure where i'm going wrong!

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the proper content type. It should be `application/Javascript` in the $.ajax call.

[Best content type to serve JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111302/best-content-type-to-serve-jsonp)

- Update:
  You have to add the callback term with the URL or with $.ajax as follows.

  http://leedsbeckett/search/getpredictivecoursetitlesearchresults**&callback=?**

or

```
url: "http://leedsbeckett/search/getpredictivecoursetitlesearchresults/",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type: "POST", **jsonp:"callback"**,
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've tried this, and i still get an error of err:r "parsererror"

Also, "Jquery 9083450845098345_509348598340598 was not called"

This might be a C# thing instead of the JQuery side?

Any help appreciated!

Andy

Comment: I have updated the answer above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for amending your answer. I'm still getting a parseerror after trying both of the suggestions above.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue as to why the JSONP wasn't returning properly from C#

Where i had jsonresult returning json, it needed to be actionresult, returning contenttype, as found after much searching here: [Can I convert a JSON string into JsonResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685155/can-i-convert-a-json-string-into-jsonresult)

Adding a contenttype then turns the string into true JSON, which the JS can read:

```
public ActionResult GetPredictiveCourseTitleSearchResults()
    {
        var jsonbuilder = "";
        var q = HttpContext.Request.Params["q"];
        var year = HttpContext.Request.Params["year"];
        var callback = HttpContext.Request.Params["callback"];
        var model = new courseModel
        {
            SearchList = GetCourses(q,year)
        };
        var results = model.SearchList.Items.ToList();
        int count = results.Count();
        int resultCount = 0;

        if (callback != "")
        {
            jsonbuilder += callback + "(";
        }
        jsonbuilder += "[";
        foreach(var result in results)
        {

            if(resultCount+1 == count)
            {
                jsonbuilder += "{\"title\":\"" + result.Fields["title"].ToString() + "\"}";
            }
            else
            {
                jsonbuilder += "{\"title\":\"" + result.Fields["title"].ToString() + "\"},";
            }

            resultCount++;
        }
        jsonbuilder += "]";
        if (callback != "")
        {
            jsonbuilder += ")";
        }
        return new ContentResult { Content = jsonbuilder, ContentType = "application/json" };
        //return Json(jsonbuilder, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Thanks for your help in diagnosing the issue Thanigainathan.